# How to repeat or concat two slice n times in one line via adapters?

Tags: rust

Can I do the same work by using iter adapters?

```
fn mutiply_bytes(buf_in: &[u8], mul: usize) -> Vec<u8> {
    let length = buf_in.len() * mul;
    let mut buf_out = Vec::with_capacity(length);
    for i in 0..length{
        buf_out.push(buf_in[i%buf_in.len()]);
    }
    buf_out
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::iter::repeat](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/fn.repeat.html) might help

```
fn mutiply_bytes(buf_in: &[u8], mul: usize) -> Vec<u8> {
    std::iter::repeat(buf_in)
        .take(mul)
        .flatten()
        .cloned()
        .collect::<Vec<u8>>()
}
```

Comment: well looks awesome